# Class org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory Was Not Found

Tags: netbeans, import, jdo, datanucleus

my team used datanucleus library for client-server application. We used version 3.0.0.
We can build the application via NetBeans successfully. The problem is, when the server-side application is run, we got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Class org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory was not found.
```

Line of code where the exception is thrown:

```
mPMF = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Utilities.SERVER_JDO_CONFIG_FILE);
```

We have included the datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.0-release.jar and it does contain the troubled org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory, so we have no idea what's going wrong here.

Anyone have experienced this before ?
Thanks before.

Comment: So why would you reference that particular class name ? it was removed from DataNucleus in v2.x, yet you're using v3.0

Comment: we're not sure which class you're referring to. But we are not particularly referencing to org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory. The implementation of JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager does that.
Thank you for the very fast reply !!

Comment: which class? which class is in the error message ? You're referring to it in your config somewhere. No other way it is brought in

Comment: "datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.0-release.jar" does NOT contain org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory. It contains "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory".

Comment: we're sorry we forgot to mention that we access the jpox.properties file. But then, we tried using JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties); where we hard-coded the jpox.properties into the properties attribute and it solved the problem !!

We're really sorry for this trouble.

Comment: @DataNucleus I cannot find a `JDOHelper` class in the `org.datanucleus.api.jdo` package. How do I get a persistence manager factory?

Comment: and why would you expect it to be in DataNucleus packages ? Part of STANDARD JDO

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using SBT, wire the settings below...

```scala
val deps_database : Seq[Setting[_]] =
  Seq(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "javax.jdo"              %   "jdo-api"                              % "3.1",
      "org.datanucleus"        %   "datanucleus-core"                     % "4.0.6",  //TODO:: Versions.datanucleus,
      "org.datanucleus"        %   "datanucleus-api-jdo"                  % "4.0.5",
      "org.datanucleus"        %   "datanucleus-jdo-query"                % "4.0.4",
      "org.datanucleus"        %   "datanucleus-rdbms"                    % "4.0.11",
      "org.datanucleus"        %   "datanucleus-mongodb"                  % "4.0.5",
      "com.h2database"         %   "h2"                                   % "1.4.185",
      "org.mongodb"            %   "mongo-java-driver"                    % "2.1.3",
      "org.postgresql"         %   "postgresql"                           % "1.4-1200-jdbc41" ))
```

... in your projects or sub-modules, like so:

```scala
lazy val root =
  project.in(file("."))
    .settings(buildInfoSettings:_*)
    .settings(disablePublishing:_*)
    .aggregate(model, data, headless)

lazy val util =
  project.in(file("util"))
    .settings(publishSettings:_*)
    .settings(librarySettings:_*)
    .settings(paranoidOptions:_*)
    .settings(otestFramework: _*)
    .settings(deps_resolvers:_*)
    .settings(deps_essential:_*)

lazy val model =
  project.in(file("model"))
    .settings(publishSettings:_*)
    .settings(librarySettings:_*)
    .settings(paranoidOptions:_*)
    .settings(otestFramework: _*)
    .settings(deps_resolvers:_*)
    .settings(deps_essential:_*)
    .settings(deps_database:_*)
    .settings(managedSources:_*)
```

You can see a complete example at: http://github.com/frgomes/poc-scala-datanucleus